# C# memory allocation

Tags: c#, new-operator, allocation, operator-keyword

- Does using operator new in c# might fail (if it requires a large memory for example)? -Solved-
- And how to discover it? -Solved-
- What other failures new operator might throw?

Thanks

Comment: Write a one-liner like int[] x = new int[100000000000] and see what happens!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `new` operator that invokes a constructor can throw any exception that you can imagine. Fro example, if *inside* the constructor it tries to allocate something big and fails, then that exception might be caught and re-raised as something more exotic.

Of course, at the point when you start seeing out-of-memory you should probably consider the process terminally ill, and put it out of its misery ASAP.

Constructors can also, despite all the rumours to the contrary, return `null` even for classes - but that is an *extreme* edge-case, bordering on the pathological.

Comment: Is returning null only possible with the evil proxy redirect I saw mentioned elsewhere or can it come about through other rare, non-malicious means?

Comment: @Dan - assuming we don't count `Nullable<T>`, then yes - the evil proxy is the only way I know of.

Answer (score 9):

If `new` fails it will throw [OutOfMemoryException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx). Additionally the constructor itself may throw any exception depending on the implementation.

From the MSDN documentation for OutOfMemoryException:

> The following Microsoft intermediate
>   (MSIL) instructions throw
>   OutOfMemoryException :
>
> - box
> - newarr
> - newobj

Answer (score 1):

> Does using operator new in c# might fail (if it requires a large memory)?

Yes. (The resource you are likely to run out of is address space, not memory per se.)

> And how to discover it?

I don't understand the question.

Comment: probably question was "how to prevent"

Comment: @TriLi This seems a better question :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it throws [`OutOfMemoryException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx)